# Collective nouns for "stewardess"?

Tags: nouns

What are the collective nouns for stewardess? Like the group of stewardess, the team ... what else could it be?

I've been trying to google it, but haven't found it yet =(

Comment: What about a "galley of flight attendants"? Or a "cabin of stewardesses” !!

Comment: Telling us that you’ve been trying to Google it is good. Telling us what searches you’ve already tried is even better. @BillJ - LOL @ “cabin of stewardesses” – if you can’t find a collective noun, make one up! (My favorite made-up collective noun was on [_Car Talk_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Car_Talk), when I heard them coin _a **shrug** of auto mechanics_.)

Comment: What about "cabin crew"? Supposing you refer to aviation. But we'd need to know the context first.

Comment: Or a *flight* of stewardesses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After having a quick search in here (https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Glossary_of_collective_nouns_by_subject) for stewardess, attendant, flight attendant, cabin crew and air stewardess and having a quick Google for "collective noun for flight attendants" and found nothing, I am confident in saying that there is **not an accepted group noun for describing a number of stewardesses**. You will therefore need to do one of two things:

1. **Use a group noun used for something else that is related in some way.** There are lots of possibilities here, so I will just list a few. *Group* would be the most generic, if there were a lot of them you could use *crowd*; I quite like *bevy*, but my personal choice would perhaps be *flock*.
2. **Make up your own group noun that either makes sense, or is humorous.** E.g. (using BillJ's suggestion in the comments) "a *cabin* of stewardesses".

A side note - assuming you are referring to an air stewardess, they don't tend to be called that nowadays; instead they are referred to as *flight attendants* or *cabin crew* in order to be gender neutral.

Answer (score -1):

Well a group of stewardesses have just me and they sounded like a bunch of geese, so how about a "gaggle" of stewardesses